# Proxy with GET request in Python request package

Tags: python, http, python-requests, proxy

I want to make a request to a proxy - but I want to use a GET request instead of using the [CONNECT method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel).
Currently I am using the Python [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) package.

I'm not experienced in this area so I'm not sure if it might be possible with another HTTP library.

I noticed that it is however possible with the [node.js request package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#proxies) when setting the `tunnel` flag to `false`.

> You can also make a standard proxied http request by explicitly
> setting tunnel : false, but note that this will allow the proxy to see
> the traffic to/from the destination server.

I really hope that someone here can help me, because I've been sitting for a few days on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the proxy argument.

```
    proxy = {
    "https": 'https://example'
    "http": 'http://example'
}

response = requests.get('https://example.com', proxies=proxy)
```